# SQLite Query is not working properly - can't load datatable

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to write a function that queries the sqlite db I have.  For some reason it does not work properly.  Below are the supporting functions that I am using.  I can get it to add tables perfectly fine.

```
    Private Sub GetSqlConnection()
        Me.SQLConnectionString = New SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
        Me.SQLConnectionString.DataSource = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "mydb.sqlite")
        Me.SQLConnectionString.Version = 3

        SQLConnection = New SQLiteConnection(Me.SQLConnectionString.ConnectionString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Query(ByVal SQLString As String)
        Try
            Dim SQLiteDRObj As SQLiteDataReader
            Dim ResultsTableObj As DataTable = Nothing
            Dim ResultSet As DataSet = Nothing
            Dim SQLAdapter As SQLiteDataAdapter = Nothing

            Me.GetSqlConnection()
            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLCommand = New SQLiteCommand(SQLConnection)
            SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLString

            SQLiteDRObj = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

            ResultsTableObj.Load(SQLiteDRObj)

            SQLiteDRObj.Close()
            SQLConnection.Close()
            SQLConnection.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[object shows as filled http://josephberardi.com/stackoverflow/objfilled.png](http://josephberardi.com/stackoverflow/objfilled.png)

[object shows as filled http://josephberardi.com/stackoverflow/exception.png](http://josephberardi.com/stackoverflow/exception.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultsTableObj` is Nothing when you call the Load method

Change this line to

```
Private Sub Query(ByVal SQLString As String)
    Try
       ....
       Dim ResultsTableObj As DataTable = New DataTable()
       ....
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I've been stressing.  I knew it was something stupid simple.